# Is there any relationship between "strict exogeneity" and "no anticipation effect" in DiD

Tags: difference-in-difference, exogeneity

Regarding "strict exogeneity" assumption, I found a discussion [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218212/what-does-strict-exogeneity-condition-of-ols-really-mean):it means that conditional on observing the data, the expectation of the error term is zero, which is something relating to **confounding variable**.

However, today, I read a recently published paper of [Miller,2021](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10940-021-09513-w) and see in **Reviewing DID Assumption** part, he said that **parallel trend** and **[strict exogeneity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/454991/what-is-the-difference-between-the-strict-exogeneity-assumption-in-ols-and-the-s)** are key assumptions.

I am wondering why the author did not mention the "no anticipation effect" assumption, which is one of the important assumption ([Assumption 2 in Borusyak, 2021](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.12419.pdf)) in staggered DiD, especially when examining the impact of a law on an outcome variable there?